# Check if current directory contains package.json and who's name is equal to value

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to do two things when I fire off a custom command in the terminal:

1. Check if the current directory has a package.json (something like checking if `process.cwd() + '/package.json'` exists).
2. Check if the name in package.json is equal to some value of "customName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `require()` can be used to load JSON files.

```
'use strict';

try {
  var packageData = require(process.cwd() + '/package.json');
} catch (e) {
  // There was no package.json
  console.log('no package.json found!');
  return;
}

console.log("name is", packageData.name);
```

Comment: Is there a similar way without a try catch? For instance, in pseudo code, if (package is not found or name != 'customName') then process.exit()?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `try`/`catch` in this situation?

Comment: I have quite a bit of logic that I did not want to include within the try. But I will abstract into their respective functions. Thanks for your help.